# Audit on dropped and recreate table

Tags: oracle, create-table, audit

I have a table that is dropped every day and then recreated.

I executed some `audit actions` on that table (`select`, `update`, `delete`, `insert`, `all`).

Now I want to use the `noaudit` command to disable `audit`, but the table is already dropped, so I get an object does not exist exception.

When this table is recreated, will the `audit` work on it?

I have version `oracle 11g`.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes..the definition will be valid if the object will be available.

Comment: So, is there a way to disable this audit before it will happen? did I need to create it myself and then execute noaudit?